# JSF Datatable Edit Using Popup Panel

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I am using JSF 1.1 with Icefaces 1.8.2

I have datatables which displays my database records.Currently when user wishes to insert or edit a record, edit button is clicked and edit form or creating form is either displayed at the bottom of datatable or in a separate page. 
Ideally I would like to display in the edit form or create form just on top of datatable like a panel popup like in the following URL.
http://postimage.org/image/pglvdcck/

How can I do this using JSF or with icefaces?

Any insight into this is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ICEFaces component ice:panelPopup. Look it up in [ICEFaces Demos](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface) - Layout panels - Popup panel.

Example - add this to your source (anywhere in the page really, even in a separate included file):

```
<ice:panelPopup modal="true" visible="#{myBean.editPopupVisible}">
  <ice:form>
    <ice:input...> some inputs...
    ... Save/Cancel button
  </ice:form>
</ice:panelPopup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So panelPopup form elements like buttons and other elements could have its own independent actions? I mean it is just like creating another form below the datatable? I presume this would work in icefaces 1.8.2!

Comment: Yes. I use popup panels casually in ICEFaces 1.8.2. It's just another component. Add an ice:panelPopup below the table, for example, with an ice:form inside (unless the panel is inside a form itself already) and all those tiny bits you want this panel to do. Then just invoke it on any action by setting visible to true (in my example. that would be setting myBean.editPopupVisible). It should be easy for you, just wrap that form of yours inside panelPopup (read in the demos how to use and configure it exactly if needed).